# "Divertente": when does it mean 'fun' or 'funny' in Italian?

Tags: adjectives

In the Collins online Italian dictionary, 'divertente' translates as both '[fun](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-italian/fun)' and '[funny](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-italian/funny)'. So if I say: "era/è stato divertente" do I mean "it was fun" or "it was funny"?

Does it depend entirely on context, i.e. should I use the reflexive verb 'divertirsi' as elaborated on [here](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/6797/correct-usage-of-the-verb-divertirsi), e.g. 'mi sono divertito' to mean fun, i.e. literally 'I funned myself' and then 'è stato divertente' to mean 'it was funny?'

Or should I really use 'buffo' for 'funny' and 'divertente' for 'fun'?

Comment: Could you please rephrase it as a question about Italian? The difference between “fun” and “funny” looks like a question about English.

Comment: I've re-worded it - thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On a dictionary, I find that (as adjective, of course) *fun* means *amusing*, whereas *funny* means *causing amusement*; there are other meanings, but just this suffices to clear up the main difference in English.

In Italian *divertente* can be both. An example for *fun* is

> a fun evening

and one for *funny* is

> a funny story

In Italian the two phrases can be rendered

> una serata divertente
>   una storia divertente

Something *buffo* is *divertente*, but they are not exact synonyms.